# Rank / Reputation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am writing an e-commerce engine that has a reputation component. I'd like users to be able to review and rate the items, and be able to rate the review.

What is the best algorithm to use to sort items based on "best" reviews? It has to be ranked by the amount of quality reviews it gets by the people who give the best reviews. I'm not sure how to translate this to algorithm.

For instance, I need to be able to compare between an item that has 5 stars from many people with low reputation, against another item that has 3 stars from a few people with high reputation.

To add to the complexity, some users may have written many reviews that are rate high / low by others, and other users may have written few reviews, but rated very high by other users. Which user is more reputable in this case?

Comment: It seams to me that most sites have decided that a single score is too inherently unprecise and opaque. Instead you see all over the place, that items have a 'avg rating' and a 'number of votes'. Then it is up to the user whether they want to gamble on the 5 votes 'perfect' item, or the '1000' votes 'quite good' item.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Yes showing two values is definitely useful. I will still need, however, to sort the items in a single list for search results. Should I perhaps derive a score from these two values and use that for sorting (but not for displaying)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you know the reputations of the users, then you might use a `UserScore` for each user such as [the one that Stackexchange uses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733).

```
UserScore = Reputation >= 200 ? 0.233 * ln(Reputation-101) - 0.75 : 0 + 1.5
```

Then you find the value of an item by summing up the user scores with the stars as weights:

```
ItemScore = \sum_i UserScore_i * Weight[Star_i]
```

where `i` is the index for the votes and `Weight` is the array involving the weights of stars.  For example, it can be `[-2 -1 0 1 2]` for a voting system of 5 stars. And one note is that you may change the weight of the 3 stars to be `+eps` if you want the items with only 3 stars to come before the items which are not evaluated.

You may change 200 and all other constants/weights accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Shouldn't the ItemScore be an average? Otherwise, an item having 50 2-star ratings will rate higher than an item having 10 5-star ratings.

Comment: @JasonBanico If we average them, then an item with a 5 star from a dominant voter would be more important than an item with 1000 5-stars from less dominant voters.

Comment: I think, to consider the two scenarios mentioned, we'll need to compute two values, a sum and an average, derive a common scale for both (say, a decimal 1 to 5 score), and then combine both in a single value. So, in my example, the one with 5-star ratings will score higher because of the averages, and in your example, the one with 1000 votes will be higher because of the sums. I also like PengOne's idea of a negative rating. Maybe in my scale, the middle number is neutral, and 1's and 2's are "poor" and "below average".

Comment: @JasonBanico You're right. The final score could be a linear combination of average score and total score. The coefficients in the interpolation would determine the importance of each.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question:

I think the trick is to weight out the people with different reputation, for instance:

A person with a reputation 2 has a vote that is 3x as heavy as the vote of another person with a lower reputation of 1. That relationship between people of different reputation is really up to you and how much you want to have the overall rating dependent on the ratings of people with low reputation. The higher the vote weight of a person with high reputation compared to a vote of a low reputation person, the less the overall reputation will change due to the low reputation votes.

So each person will have a weight let's say w_i, w_j etc.... and then the over all rating will be the weighted average of all:

example of overall rating of votes from two different persons i and j = (w_i*r_i)+(w_j*r_j)/(w_i + w_j)

where r_i, r_j are the ratings of person i and person j respectively.

To get the value of the weights of each person, you can for instance take the number of stars that person.

A good resource would be the following page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean